# how to generate tags and find mark-whole-buffer definition

Tags: help, emacs-lisp-mode

I am following the `Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp` tutorial built in in Emacs and have arrived at the `Buffer Walk-through` section.

In the 4.1 Finding more information the function `xref-find-definitions` is mentioned. As suggested - I try to find the definition of the `mark-whole-buffer` function.

when I run the function by typing `M-.` and `mark-whole-buffer`
it returns:

```
No definitions found for: mark-whole-buffer
```

Before that I have done/tried the following

---

- Installed `ctags.io` like so: `brew install --HEAD universal-ctags/universal-ctags/universal-ctags`
- run the ctags command in my `~/.emacs.d/` folder like so: `ctags -R` also tried `ctags -R *.el` - it generates a `TAGS` file and I can open it in Emacs and search with `C-s` and there is no mark-whole-buffer entry in there.
- tried similar approach in other folders (running Emacs on macOS)

  - in the `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/` folder - using same commands as in the `.emacs.d` folder
  - in the `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp` folder - using same commands as in the `.emacs.d` folder
- something else that I have tried is `M-x visit-tags-table` and when trying on for example the contents folder like `Visit tags table (default TAGS): /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/` it returns `File /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/TAGS is not a valid tags table`

---

Can you please clarify the two following points?

- Where to find the `mark-whole-buffer` function definition
- How to do so from within Emacs

Comment: `M-x xref-find-definitions` has different behaviors for different buffers, in Emacs Lisp related buffers, it will use Emacs Lisp specific backend (which is not tag) to find definitions, and tag is not needed, actually Emacs can automatically remember where a function is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-h f mark-whole-buffer` tells us that the function is defined in `simple.el`. If you click on the link in the help buffer to `simple.el`, it takes you right to the definition of the function.

Comment: It may be that the Elisp sources are not installed. In that case there is no link in the help buffer.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer and also thank you for the help and suggestions by commenters and editors. It works for me now.